# Using Dialogs for Edits in JSF apps - which component?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm looking at changing the workflow of our edit screens to be dialogs.

To get the general idea, we have a parent entity that has numerous children. Those are all in a data table component, with 'Edit' buttons beside each one.  Clicking one causes the managed bean to load up that single record into a "currentlyEditing" variable, and returns null so it stays on the same view and ajax updates a previously hidden form area to show the selected record, pre-populated for edit. At the bottom of that new form is Save and Cancel buttons, which do what you expect.   A  single button below the child list ("Add") causes a blank object to be set into the "currentlyEditing" variable, and the view now shows a clean form.   This is all pretty standard so far, right?

What my business users have asked me to do is look at changing the edit workflow.  Instead of clicking the button, and a previously-hidden area appearing below the list of children, they would like the button click to launch a dialog that contains the edit form and save/cancel buttons.  All validation errors/messaging should stay in the dialog.  It's currently undecided if a successful save should just auto-close the dialog, or if they should see a success message, and then have a button to close the dialog.  Some have suggested having both a "Save" and "Save & Close" button.

We're using Primefaces 3.5 (and would consider moving to 4.0-SNAPSHOT because our go-live is fairly distant and we're not afraid of building from source in the meantime). I see that there's a current `<p:dialog` component, but I also see there's an upcoming "Dialog Framework", but I'm just not sure what each of them is meant for.  Is a full edit form with validation messaging and managedbean round-trips, possibly even with additional dialogs launched from within that dialog, just "too much" for what `<p:dialog` was meant for? Is the Dialog Framework meant to address this/be used for such a use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you can do this with p:dialog. I've done it before, although when I did, Dialog Framework did not exist. Since you'll be using one single bean, it will be easier to apply changes made in the dialog to the table. Also since it's in the same page, dialog will appear faster (better user experience).
You'll need some javascript to clear validation messages when you reopen the dialog to prevent showing errors from last edit. But using jQuery, that will not be a problem.